# How to measure elapsed time using DateTime class?

Tags: c#, time

I am encountering a strange behavior here. Control never comes out of the do-while loop. On debugging i found that the value of the variable interval decreases during some of the loops, instead of increasing! I'm missing something obvious here, but can't figure it out.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int interval = 0;
    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;

    //Task1(); //Task1 can take 4-8 seconds to complete

    do
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);
        interval = (DateTime.Now - startTime).Milliseconds;
    } while (interval < 10000); //wait for at-least ten seconds from program start, before executing task2

    //Task2();
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your problem is that you measure the milliseconds *part* of the `TimeSpan`. You have to use `TotalMilliseconds` instead of `Milliseconds`:

```
do
{
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    interval = (DateTime.Now - startTime).TotalMilliseconds;
} while (interval < 10000); //wait for at-least ten seconds from program start, before executing task2
```

Answer (score 15):

Don't use `DateTime` for measuring time intervals.

Use `Stopwatch` class, which was designed exactly for this purpose

```
var clock = new Stopwatch();
clock.Start();
do
{
    // do something
}
while (clock.ElapsedMilliseconds < 10000)
clock.Stop();
```

Note: Of course you can use `DateTime` for measuring time, but if you need precision less then second then `Stopwatch` is right tool for the job.
And `Stopwatch` have much more readable and easy to use methods for measuring time

In your particular case: *"wait for at-least ten seconds from program start, before executing task2"* you can use asynchronous approach

```
var task1 = StartTask1();

await Task.Delay(10000); // next line will be executed approximately after 10 s

var task2 = StartTask2();
```

Comment: Thank you for the sample code...Stopwatch is definitely better than DateTime for measurement of elapsed time.

Answer (score 3):

With `TimeSpan` you always have to use the `Total` properties if you want to know the *total* time that has passed. All properties without `Total` in front of them only display the *current amount* of time that has passed.

For example: A method runs for 1 minute and 7 seconds.

```
Console.WriteLine(ts.Seconds);
```

Output:

> 7

Why is that? Because there are only 60 seconds in a minute and `ts.Seconds` will start increasing again from 0 to 59.

Compare this to

```
Console.WriteLine(ts.TotalSeconds),
```

Output:

> 67

Now we have the total amount of seconds that have passed, in this case 67 seconds.

Answer (score 3):

I created the following struct as a simple-to-use timer as an alternative to [`System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.8).  The `Stopwatch` class works just fine and truly does provide high-precision interval checking on the Windows systems I use.  In some cases, though, I prefer the simpler API offered by `EasyTimer` over having to start/restart/stop the `Stopwatch`.  This is especially true when I don't need to be highly accurate with the interval, just in-the-ballpark.  As a value type, it doesn't add any pressure to the garbage collector, and it's slightly more efficient (as a micro optimization) to check the interval with `EasyTimer` than it is with `Stopwatch`.

```
public struct EasyTimer
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a value indicating whether or not the time interval has elapsed.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>
    /// If the time interval has elapsed, the timer is reset to check the next time interval.
    /// </remarks>
    public bool HasElapsed
    {
        get
        {
            var nowTicks = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
            if (nowTicks - this.startTicks < this.intervalTicks) { return false; }
            this.startTicks = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
            return true;
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="EasyTimer"/> structure with the
    /// time interval to check.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="intervalInMilliseconds">
    /// The time interval to check in milliseconds.
    /// </param>
    public EasyTimer(int intervalInMilliseconds)
    {
        this.intervalTicks = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(intervalInMilliseconds).Ticks;
        this.startTicks    = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
    }

    private          long startTicks;
    private readonly long intervalTicks;
}
```

Here's an example of what I use it for.  Consider...

```
using System.Threading;
private ManualResetEvent shutdownEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

// Allow external user to signal work to stop.
public void Shutdown()
{
    this.shutdownEvent.Set();
}

private void DoWork()
{
    // This approach requires checking the event each time through the loop,
    // which involves overhead I wish to minimize.
    while (!this.shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0))
    {
        // Do some ongoing work here...
    }
}
```

Here's an approach that minimizes the overhead using `Stopwatch`, but note the additional complexity.

```
using System.Threading;
private ManualResetEvent shutdownEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

// Allow external user to signal work to stop.
public void Shutdown()
{
    this.shutdownEvent.Set();
}

private void DoWork()
{
    var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    while (true)
    {
       // Do some ongoing work here...

       // Check the ShutdownEvent every second.
       if (sw.ElapsedMilliseconds >= 1000)
       {
           if (this.shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0)) { break; }
           sw.Restart();
       }
    }
}
```

Finally, here's an approach using `EasyTimer`.

```
using System.Threading;
private ManualResetEvent shutdownEvent = new ManualResetEvent(false);

// Allow external user to signal work to stop.
public void Shutdown()
{
    this.shutdownEvent.Set();
}

private void DoWork()
{
    var et = new EasyTimer(1000);
    while (true)
    {
       // Do some ongoing work here...

       // Check the ShutdownEvent every second (or so).
       if (et.HasElapsed && this.shutdown.WaitOne(0)) { break; }
    }

    // or alternatively...
    // while (!(et.HasElapsed && this.shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0))
    // {
    //     // Do some ongoing work here...
    // }
}
```